# Regex for markdown url on all urls in golang

Tags: regex, go, infinite-loop

I am trying to work through a markdown file, replacing all the image urls. The format of a markdown image url is `![alternative name](imageurl.png)`

My regex search finds the first one, returns the location and I replace it, I then cycle through the document until my regex search doesnt find any - i.e its array of match dimensions is empty.

The problem is for some reason it continues to match on "i dont exactly know what". I.e the length of the array returned from the regex search is never 0

```
location := split[:locationSplit]

bodyRe := regexp.MustCompile(`!\[(.*)\]\((.*)\)`)
indexes := bodyRe.FindStringIndex(body)
fmt.Println("location: ", absoluteFileLocation)
fmt.Println("length: ", indexes)

for len(indexes) != 0 {
    fmt.Println("length: ", len(indexes))
    imageLocation := body[indexes[0]:indexes[1]]
    body = body[:indexes[0]] + imageLocation + body[indexes[1]:]
    indexes = indexes[:0]
    fmt.Println("length: ", len(indexes))
    indexes = bodyRe.FindStringIndex(body)
}
```

this returns a continual:

```
length:  2
length:  0
length:  2
length:  0
length:  2
length:  0
length:  2
length:  0
length:  2
```

the 2's come from the line `indexes = bodyRe.FindStringIndex(body)` inside the loop as I set indexes to 0 just before.

Help appreciated

EDIT: Edit due to request for example included. The above method is clearly flawed, this following method works for the first image, but not for the next ones

So I attempted this technique:

(sample markdown file)

```
some markdown

![image](anImage.png)

more markdown

![image2](anImage2.png)

more markdown & end of document
```

and the the revised code:

```
...
...
    bodyRe := regexp.MustCompile(`!\[(.*)\]\((.*)\)`)
    indexes := bodyRe.FindAllStringSubmatchIndex(body, -1)

    for _, j := range(indexes) { //i is the index, j is the element (in this case j = []int )
        imageLocation := body[j[4]:j[5]]
        body = body[:j[4]] + "/App/Image/?image=" + location + "/" + imageLocation + body[j[5]:]
    }
    return body
```

(required output markdown)

```
some markdown

![image](/App/Image/?image=[location]/anImage.png)

more markdown

![image2](/App/Image/?image=[location]/anImage2.png)

more markdown
end of document
```

And that works for the first image. But not the second one. The problem is (I think that when that method loops through and replaces the first one, the indexes in body (i.e `body[j[4]:j[5]]`) change and so it replaces the second one in the wrong place.

I need to do this so that when the markdown is eventually rendered the image urls point to places where they can be served from.

EDIT: Fixed

Thanks guys.
Due to the fact that people struggled to understand what I wanted to do, I suspect that I am going about the problem in a strange way. I have got it working and below is the code snippet that works for any one else looking into this.

Firstly I will explain why I had the problem.
I wanted to seperate out the writing of blogs for a site, from the actual maintenance of the site itself. Therefore 'blog writers' were told to write blogs in markdown, with all image tags in the format of ` where all images must be in the same directory as the markdown file itself.
Because this directory is not part of the code base of the website itself, the image urls needed replacing with the absolute urls so they could be served. I didnt want this to be something the blog writers needed to worry about.

Everything worked fine for the first image, but because the replacement absolute URL changed the length and therefore the positions of all of the characters in the blog contents, the indexes that the regex found, no longer aligned, so I had to add the new length to the indexes of matches.

```
adjustment := 0
for _, j := range(indexes) {
    imageLocation := body[j[4]+adjustment:j[5]+adjustment]

    replacement := "?imageurl=" + url.QueryEscape(location) + "/" + imageLocation
    body = body[:j[4] + adjustment] + replacement + body[j[5] + adjustment:]
    adjustment += len(replacement) - len(imageLocation)
}
```

Comment: I don't have time to dig into this, but what happens if stop re-using the `indexes` slice? I'm pretty skeptical of that code. Just at a glance you're doing a bunch of re-slicing, given I have to stop and think about what the collection is like after each line of code, that is probably where your error happens.

Comment: Is it possible to restate the problem in terms of a sample input and the desired output?

Comment: Markdown image links can also specify a title: `![alt text](/path/to/img.jpg "Title")` And what about the perfectly valid markdown of `![alt text][id]` then later `[id]: /path/to/img.jpg "Title"`? Trying to parse things with regexps is often at best difficult and error prone. Surely there must be a markdown parser available in Go.

Comment: Yup there is a markdown parser. The problem is I am hosting the markdown and images for display from a golang web server. The server needs to know the location of the images. When the author of the markdown puts a relative path, I need to change that to an absolute path. You are right though, so I restrict the markdown authors to just image relative location and the images must be in the same directory as the markdown file itself.

Answer (score 0):

After this line:

```
imageLocation := body[indexes[0]:indexes[1]]
```

`imageLocation` will contain a string like `![image](anImage.png)`.

```
body = body[:indexes[0]] + imageLocation + body[indexes[1]:]
```

After that line, body will be the same as it was before. You're basically reconstructing it out of 3 segments.

This is equivalent to doing [the following](http://play.golang.org/p/UUk5A_oHwv):

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    s := "Hello, playground"
    t := s[2:4]
    s = s[:2] + t + s[4:]
    fmt.Println(s) // prints "Hello, playground"
}
```

In the next iteration, the same left-most match will be found again, ad perpetuum.

Have you read the documentation for [`FindStringIndex`](http://golang.org/pkg/regexp/#Regexp.FindStringIndex)?

If you edit your question to say what you're trying to do I can provide you with a working code snippet.

Comment: Ive updated the original question with a working version now. Thanks